# MySQL - Multiple Conditions and Their Results with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

```
table name : users u
id   username   src
 1   mark       101
 2   stanley    102
 3   john       103
 4   stewe      104


table name : call_history c
id   src        dst        duration
 1   101        555-1217   20    
 2   555-1315   102        30
 3   555-2245   102        40
 4   102        555-6523   30
 5   102        555-4213   20
 6   555-1689   102        15
 7   103        555-1775   35
```

**There are two tables and these columns.
Conditions are;**

```
SUM(duration)   AS OutboundSUM (Condition: u.src=c.src )
COUNT(duration) AS OutboundCNT (Condition: u.src=c.src )

SUM(duration)   AS InboundSUM  (Condition: u.src=c.dst )
COUNT(duration) AS InboundCNT  (Condition: u.src=c.dst )
```

**What I need to see with Group By per username;**

```
username   OutboundSUM OutboundCNT  InboundSUM  InboundCNT
mark       20          1            0           0
stanley    50          2            85          3
john       35          1            0           0
stewe       0          0            0           0
```

I tried UNION ALL, sub query after select, INNER JOIN but It didn't work.
Union gives me 2 line for each username, join makes me crazy, sub queries takes longtime and wrong results.

All help is appreciated.

Problem, solved with Kicstart's solution. Thank you very much for each help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the primary keys of the table? It would help us give better answers. 
Also, you MUST include both conditions u.src=c.src AND u.id=c.id for join. 
If the IDs of the two tables do not relate to each other, I suggest you use different attribute names.

Comment: Primary Keys are Id coloumns, but not related. Only connection is src fileds.

Comment: Okay then use different attribute names, cause you might be confusing the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of sub queries?

```
SELECT a.src,
        oBSum AS OutboundSUM,
        oBCnt AS OutboundCNT,
        iBSum AS InboundSUM,
        iBCnt AS InboundCNT
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT src, SUM(duration) AS oBSum, COUNT(*) AS oBCnt FROM call_history GROUP BY src) ob
ON u.src = ob.src
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT dst, SUM(duration) AS iBSum, COUNT(*) AS iBCnt FROM call_history GROUP BY dst) ib
ON u.src = ib.dst
```

Comment: I tried that with little change, I added GROUP BY u.username end of the grand query. Without that, results has the same usernames multiple times. Anyway, results was wrong again;

Comment: Spotted typo in the 2nd sub query (wrong group by column). Corrected and now should give the right results. It should not need a group by on the main query.